# How to specify an endpoint's authorization is optional in openapi v3?

Tags: openapi

I'm trying to document an existing API that contains various endpoints whose authentication is optional.  That is, more data is returned if the user is authorized than if they were not authorized.

Could not find that explicitly in the OAspec v3.  Is there a coding trick to define this situation?

My present work-around is to code for authorization, yet in a description of the endpoint write that authorization is optional.  This works and seems adequate.  Yet the purist in me wonders if there is another way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To make security optional, add an empty requirement `{}` to the `security` array:

```yaml
security:
  - {}   # <----
  - api_key: []
```

This means the endpoint can be called with or without security.

Source: [this comment](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/14#issuecomment-297457320) in the OpenAPI Spec repository.

Comment: Bravo, Helen!  Tested this minutes ago, and the behavior now seen when running the OpenAPI file using swagger-ui is just what I originally wanted.

Answer (score 3):

I just learned that security: can have an array of hash maps that cater to multiple authentication protocols.

Two examples:

```
security: # protocol A or protocol B
    - A
    - B

security: protocol A and protocol B
    - A
      B
```

Comment: That is probably one of the most clear and concise descriptions of how security requirement objects work.  We tried to make it clear but it wasn't easy :-)

Comment: Is it possible to make one as required and one as optional?